How to get the correct URL in SharePoint API using Python

I already tried to use below format but it only returns an html code like and not my desired output, I want to know the correct URL to use to proceed.
I use format but did not output as I expected: WebSiteURL/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Documents')/items?$select=Title
Python code:
## Set up the headers with the Authorization field containing the Access Token
headers = {
    'Authorization': "Bearer " + json_data['access_token'],    # Get access token here json_data['access_token']
    'Accept':'application/json;odata=verbose',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json;odata=verbose'
}

url = "WebSiteURL/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Automated NTE')/items?$select=Title"

## GET request 
l = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

print(l.text)

Note that I replacing the 'WebSiteURL' by my actual SharePoint site.
